# Jquery script to DEMO Test PHP REST Service using Slim Framework

Tags: php, jquery, json, slim

I create a simple REST service with Slim PHP framework. You can retrive the Mayan calendar in JSON format:

Example: https://snap.apigee.com/HUN6NV or

http://almanac.alwaysdata.net/openalmanac/getMayanCalendar/

Now I would like to call it with latest JQuery Framework.

I write a very simple HTML helper:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Example!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/base.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</head>
<body> etc etc....
```

I use http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js in a very simple HTML example that call this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $.getJSON('http://almanac.alwaysdata.net/openalmanac/getMayanCalendar/',
    function(data) {
      alert('Fetched ' + data.length + ' items!');
    });
});
```

But doesn't works! I am very sad and I don't understand what's the problem!!

Can you help me...with a very simple code working??

Thank you for you help!!

Comment: Is the web service hosted on same server as of your HTML ? may be this issue is related to same origin policy ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error I see is just in using the .lenght with the 'data' variable, which is not appropriate, the rest is "by the book". See this one working:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.getJSON('http://192.168.41.94/Admin/Open/JSON/data.php', '',
        function(data)
        {
            // NOPE: alert('Fetched ' + data.length + ' items!');
            $.each(data, function(key, val) { alert(key + ' is ' + val); });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Umberto, and congratulations on your first accepted answer! I removed your signature from the answer (in review right now). Remember that your user card is always visible below the answer. Adding your name to the answer is just noise, and it will be removed. Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and visit [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you have any questions.